# Express js manipulate data before render view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new using nodejs and express
and was wondering what is the best practice to manipulate data before render a view. Currently i want to set some variables based on the retrieved data to render the view. So far this is what i have, but I am not sure if this is the best practice or if there is any better way to do it.

```
var request = require('request');

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  request.get('http://nout.nout-app.com/getAccessVIPForUserId/' + req.params.id, function(err, resp, body) {
    var bodyResp = JSON.parse(body);

    bodyResp.data.forEach(function(el, index, array){
      if(el.access_status === '1') {
        el.status = 'success';
      } else {
        el.status = 'warning';
      }

      if(el.access_friend === '1') {
        el.access_friend = 'yes';
      } else {
        el.access_friend = 'no';
      }
    });

    console.log(bodyResp.data);
      if(err || (typeof bodyResp.data === 'undefined' || bodyResp.data === null)) {
        res.render('error', {
          message: bodyResp.reason ? bodyResp.reason : 'Something went wrong',
          error: {
            status: 500
          }
        });
      } else {
        res.render('profile', {
            intern: true,
            user: req.user,
            invitations: bodyResp.data
        });
      }
  });
};
```

I appreciate if you guys could give me guide in this and also suggest some good material to improve. Regards.

Comment: Without knowing too much about your project constraints and goals, this looks like perfectly fine code. What do you think might need changing?

Comment: Since the async nature of nodejs I am not sure if looping like that trough an array would be like blocking code if I have too much data to loo trough.

that is why I am not completely sure about the code I wrote, but, since I dont have too much experience with nodejs and express I can not think in any other way to handle that.

Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `.forEach` is blocking (synchronous), but it is *extremely fast*. In general you don't need to worry about for basic data manipulation like that. Remember - async doesn't make something take less time, it just gives other things the ability to keep happening in the mean time.

If you really want to make your loop async, have a look at the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) module. `async.each` is an async version of `.forEach`